# Two different formats of field in report Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, events, format, ms-access-2013, onload-event

I'm trying to find a way to do the following:

I want to have two different formats for a certain text box. To do so, I've done the following: User types one or two digits in a form text box(who's input and format are both "#,0;0;_") and has "yes/no" box on the right of that number field which asks if it's "kg per bag"(so by default it's the other measurement unit which is Percentages), then an OnLoad event is fired when viewing the report for that form, which checks if the yes/no value is yes or no. If "yes" then the format is set to "#.0 & " kg/bag"", if no it's set to "#.0 & " %"".

I will have to additionally divide by 100 when percentages are the ones picked, but first I want the whole thing to work... Which I still can't do!

Sadly, I'm nowhere near getting it to work... Here is my current macro on the onload event of the report, which is marked as not valid expression:

[Link to the image on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LlpD.png)

Or here is the MacroBuilder Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<UserInterfaceMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application"><UserInterfaceMacro For="Report" Event="OnLoad"><Statements><ConditionalBlock><If><Condition>[yn]=False</Condition><Statements><Action Name="SetValue"><Argument Name="Item">[Text0].[Format]</Argument><Argument Name="Expression">#,0 &amp; " kg/bag"</Argument></Action></Statements></If><Else><Statements><Action Name="SetValue"><Argument Name="Item">[Text0].[Format]</Argument><Argument Name="Expression">#,0 &amp; " %"</Argument></Action></Statements></Else></ConditionalBlock></Statements></UserInterfaceMacro></UserInterfaceMacros>
```

Which is displayed as:

```
If [yn]=False Then
    SetValue
        Item = [text0].[format]
        Expression = #,0 & " kg/bag"
Else
    SetValue
        Item = [text0].[format]
        Expression = #,0 & " %"
End if
```

Can anyone give me a hint on where to go with this? Thank you!!

P.S. Comma is my decimal separator in regional settings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to change format only concatenate the numeric value with unit (kg/bag or %).

Using VBA, try the following code in the OnLoad event (I am assuming the recordsource field behind the text0 control is called the same -text0):

```
If Forms!yourformname![yn] = False Then
    Reports!yourreportname!text0 = Me.text0 & " kg/bag" 
Else
    Reports!yourreportname!text0 = (Me.text0)/100 & "%"
    ' ALTERNATIVELY: Reports!yourreportname!text0.Format = "percent"
End If
```

Alternatively in the OnLoad event, use an embedded macro or call an external macro with the following one action (if/then changed into the IIF function):

```
SetValue 
Item: text0
Expression: =IIF(Forms!yourformname![yn] = False, text0 & " kg/bag", text0/100 & "%")
```